# Attempted import error: 'signInUserWithEmailAndPassword' is not exported from 'firebase/auth'

Tags: firebase-authentication, es6-modules

please i need your help
I'm using **Firebase 9.02** and i'm facing a problem when i try to *import signInUserWithEmailAndPassword* to sign in my users with **Firebase authentication** module

Is it a problem in the **version 9** of **Firebase** ?

Thank you in advance

````
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./SignUpScreen.css";
import auth from "../firebase";
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInUserWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

// import auth from "../firebase";

const SignUpScreen = () => {
    const emailRef = useRef(null);
    const passwordRef = useRef(null);


    const signIn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailRef, passwordRef)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = userCredential.user;
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className='signupScreen'>
            <form>
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <input
                    ref={emailRef}
                    className='signin'
                    type='email'
                    placeholder='Email'
                />
                <input
                    ref={passwordRef}
                    className='signin'
                    type='password'
                    placeholder='Password'
                />
                <button onClick={signIn} className='signin' type='submit'>
                    Sign In
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignUpScreen;```
````

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the error is not a problem with version 9 of the Firebase SDK.

The issue is that the method is wrongly spelt.

It's `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and not `signInUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password)

Comment: yes, you're right
problem fixed
thank you Mr. Victor